# Tomcat 7 not starting with grails app

Tags: grails, tomcat7

My app runs on my machine but not im tomcat this is my log :

```
Oct 12, 2012 2:48:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
Oct 12, 2012 2:48:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 12, 2012 2:48:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 12, 2012 2:48:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 904 ms
Oct 12, 2012 2:48:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 12, 2012 2:48:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
Oct 12, 2012 2:48:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/fypTomcat/webapps/FYP.war
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.cfg.ConfigurationHelper).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Configuring Spring Security UI ...
... finished configuring Spring Security UI


Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

Oct 12, 2012 2:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Oct 12, 2012 2:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/FYP] startup failed due to previous errors
Oct 12, 2012 2:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/FYP] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 12, 2012 2:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/FYP] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@16394576] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 12, 2012 2:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/FYP] appears to have started a thread named [com.fyp.timeline.Role.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 12, 2012 2:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/FYP] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.ThreadLocalMapHandler] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo$ThreadLocalMapHandler@746231ed]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@5abbfa4c]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Oct 12, 2012 2:49:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 12, 2012 2:49:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 12, 2012 2:49:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 51609 ms
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        101,1         Bot
```

Any Ideas what causes this?

Comment: Is that _all_ the log you have?  The "startup failed due to previous errors" message usually means the real cause is further back in the log file (or in one of the other log files).

Comment: I have edited to add the full log files, There is nothing relevant in any of the other logs.

Comment: Does it work with `grails run-war`?  The Log4J messages look suspect, is this an app you've upgraded from an earlier version of Grails?  Maybe you have an out-of-date web.xml in your `src/templates`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be the solution to your problem -

http://java.dzone.com/articles/tomcat-6-infamous-%E2%80%9Csevere

Answer (score 5):

This is a message from `catalina.out` file. Take a look at `localhost.[date].log` (e.g. `localhost.2012-10-12.log`). It should contain all details and stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

we had this error because of the log4j config. You need to change it to write to the tomcat log directory.

It seems it is now fixed in 2.1.4+ version of Grails. See http://grails.org/2.1.4%20Release%20Notes